# Движение объекта по свайпу.(Unity 2d)

Tags: unity3d, swipe

Есть код с помощью которого объект  по свайпу двигается вправо,  влево,  вверх,  вниз без остановки. Но почему то объект нормально двигается только вверх и вниз. А вправо и влево не всегда. Как это можно исправить. Спасибо заранее.

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothMove : MonoBehaviour
{

private Vector2 startTouchPosition, endTouchPosition;
private Vector3 startRocketPosition, endRocketPosition;
private float flyTime;
private float flightDuration = 100f;

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        startTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        endTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

        if ((endTouchPosition.x < startTouchPosition.x) && transform.position.x > -100f)
            StartCoroutine(Fly("left"));

        if ((endTouchPosition.x > startTouchPosition.x) && transform.position.x < 100f)
            StartCoroutine(Fly("right"));

        if ((endTouchPosition.y > startTouchPosition.y) && transform.position.y < 100f)
            StartCoroutine(Fly("up"));

        if ((endTouchPosition.y < startTouchPosition.y) && transform.position.y > -100f)
            StartCoroutine(Fly("down"));
    }
}

private IEnumerator Fly(string whereToFly)
{
    switch (whereToFly)
    {
        case "left":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startRocketPosition = transform.position;
            endRocketPosition = new Vector3
                (startRocketPosition.x - 100f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flightDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp
                    (startRocketPosition, endRocketPosition, flyTime / flightDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;

        case "right":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startRocketPosition = transform.position;
            endRocketPosition = new Vector3
                (startRocketPosition.x + 100f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flightDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp
                    (startRocketPosition, endRocketPosition, flyTime / flightDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;
        case "up":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startRocketPosition = transform.position;
            endRocketPosition = new Vector3
                (startRocketPosition.x, transform.position.y + 100f, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flightDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp
                    (startRocketPosition, endRocketPosition, flyTime / flightDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;
        case "down":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startRocketPosition = transform.position;
            endRocketPosition = new Vector3
                (startRocketPosition.x, transform.position.y - 100f, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flightDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp
                    (startRocketPosition, endRocketPosition, flyTime / flightDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Свайп и движение это две абсолютно разные и независимые друг от друга ответственности. Они не должны знать о существовании друг друга. Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно.

```
public interface ISwipeTarget
{
    void OnSwipe (Vector2 side);
}

public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _swipeDistance = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _inputTarget; // кому посылаем импуты
    private ISwipeTarget _target;
    private Vector2 _touchDownPosition;
    private bool _swipe;

    private void Start ()
    {
        if (_inputTarget != null)
            _target = _inputTarget.GetComponent<ISwipeTarget>();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Touch Touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
            switch (Touch0.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    _touchDownPosition = Touch0.position;
                    _swipe = true;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    _swipe = false;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    if (Vector2.Distance(_touchDownPosition, Touch0.position) > _swipeDistance) {
                        Vector2 Vector = Touch0.position-_touchDownPosition;
                        // надо опредилить куда сместилось больше, по X или Y
                        if (Math.Abs(Vector.x) > Math.Abs(Vector.y))
                            OnSwipe(Vector.x > 0 ? Vector2.right : Vector2.left);
                        else
                            OnSwipe(Vector.y > 0 ? Vector2.up : Vector2.down);
                        _swipe = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSwipe (Vector2 side)
    {
        if (_target != null)
            _target.OnSwipe(side);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour, ISwipeTarget
{
    [SerializeField] private float _time = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _distance = 100f;
    // с кривой как-то красивше
    [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _curve = new AnimationCurve(new[] { new Keyframe(0, 0, 2, 2), new Keyframe(1, 1, 0, 0) });
    private Transform _transform;
    private IEnumerator _courutine;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _transform = transform;
    }

    public void OnSwipe (Vector2 side)
    {
        // запуск новой корутины не останавливает предыдущюю
        if (_moveCourutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(_courutine);
        _courutine = Coroutine(side);
        StartCoroutine(_courutine);
    }

    private IEnumerator Coroutine (Vector2 side)
    {
        Vector3 Start = _transform.position;
        Vector3 Finish = Start+(Vector3)side*_distance;
        float Timer = 0;
        while (Timer < _time)
        {
            float Way = Timer/_time;
            float WayCurve = _curve.Evaluate(Way);
            _transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(Start, Finish, WayCurve);
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        _transform.position = Finish;
    }
}
```

Comment: А как можно объединить эти 2 кода?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        endTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        string flyType = "";
        if ((endTouchPosition.x < startTouchPosition.x) && transform.position.x > -100f)
            flyType = "left";

        if ((endTouchPosition.x > startTouchPosition.x) && transform.position.x < 100f)
            flyType = "right";

        if ((endTouchPosition.y > startTouchPosition.y) && transform.position.y < 100f)
            flyType = "up";

        if ((endTouchPosition.y < startTouchPosition.y) && transform.position.y > -100f)
            flyType = "down";

        StartCoroutine(Fly(flyType));
    }
```